# Log Bson query in javascript form

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb

Using Java I create a complex MongoDB query and before execute it usually I log the query:

```
log.info("Filter: {}", queryFilter);
```

The log is usefull but the `queryFilter` is printed is this form:

```
And Filter{filters=[Filter{fieldName='FinInstrmGnlAttrbts.ClssfctnTp', value=RFBTCB}, [...] ]}
```

I would like to log the query in "Javascript form" in the same way it should execute directly into MongoDB, like:

```
{$and : [ {'FinInstrmGnlAttrbts.ClssfctnTp' : 'RFBTCB'}, [...] ]}
```

In this way, if a day an error will occur I can take directly the query from the log and test it in MongoDB, without retype the entire query manually.

Is it possible in any way?

Comment: I haven't used it but taking a peek at the API docs (version 3.5, latest) and guessing the type of `queryFilter` to be `BasicDBObject` I see that there's a [toJson](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/javadoc/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html#toJson--) method. Right now you're getting the results of the `toString` method. What happens if you log `queryFilter.toJson()` instead?

Comment: `queryFilter` is a `org.bson.conversions.Bson` object and it hasn't a `toJson` method.

Comment: Are you sure? That's not a concrete type, that's an interface. Try calling `getClass()` on it to find out what it really is, then cast it to its concrete type.

Comment: I can't cast it because my `queryFilter` is a `com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.AndFilter` and this class is private. And in a more general way I couldn't cast it because I couldn't know how the `queryFilter` was composed (it could be an `AndFilter` or an `OrFilter` or ...)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved with

```
BsonDocument bsonDocument = queryFilter.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry());
log.info("Filter: {}", bsonDocument);
```